# ffmpeg concatenates two videos but the output video has a little white glitch after the end of the first one. How to correct?

Tags: ffmpeg, concatenation, video-editing

I'm trying to merge two videos into one using ffmpeg.

Here's the command I use:

> *ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i files.txt -c copy output.mp4*

Where the files.txt has:

> *file '/Users/user.name/Desktop/Part1.mp4' file.  '/Users/user.name/Desktop/Part2.mp4'*

The output video is fine, except for a little momentary white glitch after the end of the first video. How to I correct it?

P.S. I used to use this utility on an ubuntu machine previously and it worked like a charm always. This is the first time I'm using it on a mac (installed ffmpeg using homebrew).

P.P.S. I tried again in the old ubuntu machine, got the same glitch there too.

*Many thanks in advance.*

Comment: Could you make sure that there aren't any white frames at the end of the first video or at the beginning of the second video? If there aren't any, do they have audio? If so what happens if you encode only video?

Comment: @kesh There aren't any white frames in any of the videos. 
Yes, both of them have audios. I, in fact, have an audio file separately. Can you guide me on how to encode/concat only video?

Comment: Add `-an` (as in "no audio" initials backwards) to your output options. If this makes the difference, you can keep the audio and try `-vsync 0` to stop ffmpeg from trying to align video & audio. (Even if it fixes the issue, make sure video & audio stay in sync at the end of the concatenated video)

Comment: The "-an" flag didn't help either. Can still see the glitch.

Comment: What if you try `ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i files.txt -an -c:v copy -vsync 0 output.mp4`?

Comment: Still seeing the glitch.

Comment: I'm running out of ideas but the final thing that I can think of is to see if using `concat` filter instead: `ffmpeg -i part1.mp4 -i part2.mp4 -filter_complex [0:v][0:a][1:v][1:a]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[outv][outa] -map [outv] -map [outa] out.mp4` Ignore the re-encoding quality for now and see if the glitch goes away if you re-encode instead of copy.

Comment: Sincerely appreciate all the help. :)
But I'm still seeing the glitch.

Comment: @Chetan were you able to remove the glitch? I'm in the same situation

Comment: @EmmanuelGarciaMartinez It just started working for me, don't remember if anything specifically helped. Here's the command I use:

ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i files.txt -c copy output.mp4

Hope it works for you too. I would otherwise use iMovie to achieve this now.

Comment: @Chetan Thanks, yes I was able to solve it but now I have another error hahaha, when I have videos from the back and front cameras, some of them flip vertically with the command you mentioned, it's weird